# I can't install new packages and can't update and upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, process, apt, dpkg

I'm trying to install some program on Ubuntu, but when I try it I got the following error.-

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Searching on the WEB, I applied this.-

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo kill -TERM <PID>
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Apparently it works until the second line, but when I execute the third line the terminal doesn't answer (marks that it continues downloading a program that I tried previously to install. I left the PC works with this, one day, waiting for the end of this but nothing happened).

The previous program that I tried to install is Dropbox.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What was the exact package name you tried to install, and the actual command you used?

Comment: Wireshark, but it happens with any package.
`sudo apt-get install vlc` (for example)

Comment: Check for existing processes. `ps aux | grep apt` or `ps aux | grep dpkg`.

Answer (score 7):

Run the following:

```
fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

If there are processes running, and any of the 2 files exist, then run:

```
fuser -k /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

Then `fuser` will send a `SIGKILL` signal to each process.  That should resolve the issue.

---

If the above does not work for you, then you may want to take a look at this:

- [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/a/102084)

Comment: Ok. I used it and apparently it worked, but the Dropbox is still downloading. I tried to remove Dropbox via Ubuntu Software Center and the software center show me this: `Waiting to dpkg to exit`. The link that you provided me I had already used and I can't solve my problem.

Comment: My solution: reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: well, that's always an option :p

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu 16.0.4 above  then type below command on terminal

```
 ps -A | grep apt
```

If  you are using ubuntu version less than 16.0.4 then type below command,

```
 ps -A | grep apt-get
```

It will give you the currently running process id. If you kill that process then your problem will be solved.

For killing, process try out below command:

```
sudo kill -TERM  process_id
```

e.g : `sudo kill -TERM 18846`